# How to implement Statsmodels Multinomial Logistic Regression (MNLogit) wald_test()?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels, multinomial

I'm (a Python newbie) writing Python code to mimic outputs in SAS and want to run a multinomial logistic regression on the SAS Wallet data set. I've done normal logistic regression previously on other data using statsmodels.Logit, but now am using statsmodels.MNLogit. According to the API (https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.MultinomialResults.html#statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.MultinomialResults) there is a .wald_test() method on the fitted MultinomialResults model, but it's throwing "**TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, tuple found**" when I try to use it with a String/tuple parameter value for r_matrix (there are also no examples for how the test should be used on the wald_test() page (https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.MultinomialResults.wald_test.html#statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.MultinomialResults.wald_test).

This is the code I input (where df is a pandas dataframe of the Wallet data):

```
#Define X and Y
X = df[['Male','Business','Punish','Explain']]
X = sm.add_constant(X)
Y = df['Wallet']

#Fit model
mnlogit_1 = sm.MNLogit(Y,X).fit()

#Run Wald test (on constant)
wald = ('const = 0')
Results = mnlogit_1.wald_test(wald)
print("const:", Results)
```

The same code works for sm.Logit() on a different data set (one that works with binomial logistic regression).
Does anyone have an idea for what's going wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: `wald = ('const = 0')` is indeed a tuple, try `wald = 'const = 0'`

Comment: @HenriqueAndrade Still the same error ("need a bytes-like object, tuple found") :( The documentation indicates that it should be able to take arrays, strings, and tuples